# Remotely start services with Powershell

Tags: c#, teamcity, powershell-2.0

I have a Powershell script that starts a service on a remote machine.

It does something like this:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $serverName -ScriptBlock { param($serviceexe) & $serviceexe -install }-ArgumentList $localExePath
```

It works OK in a local machine and also in Teamcity as a Build step.

But when I am trying to start the service from some other tool, I am getting the message:

`"cannot start service from the command line or a debugger".`

This other tool is written in C#, using `System.Management.Automation.`

I´ve also tried it using Process class, but still the same problem.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered [Powershell Remote Requirements](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-en/library/dd315349.aspx) already?